# Difference between logical and virtual addresses

Tags: addressing

Today I heard that a:

- DMA-controller is mapping/converting logical addresses (from I/O-Mapping) to physical addresses
- MMU-controller is mapping/converting virtual addresses to physical addresses

So now I'm really confused! What is the difference between logical and virtual addresses? Why do we need that new type of address (logical address)?

Comment: Offset address vs. completely different address scheme.

Answer (score 5):

Logical address: the address as the CPU instruction set is using. Note that there can be many more such addresses than there is RAM (or other memory or IO) in the system.

Physical address: the address that is sent to the RAM (or ROM, or IO) for a read or write operation.

For a simple system, physical address = logical address. Larger systems are generally demand-paged virtual memory systems, where the MMU translates a logical address to a physical address, or alerts the OS to take action (to allocate a page, read a page from disk, or deny access to a page -> trap or fault).

```
"DMA-controller is mapping/converting logical addresses (from I/O-Mapping) to physical addresses"
```

I don't understand that sentence, maybe I am missing some context. In the cases I know, the DMA works on physical addresses. (A DMA working on logical addresses is possible, but less efficient because each DMA transfer would involve the MMU. But it would be easier to use.)

Answer (score 2):

@Wouter already gave a good explanation. I'll highlight a couple of things:

logical addresses are those seen and used by the assembly programmer, whereas physical addresses are those directly corresponding to the logic levels of the hardware address bus.

Those are the two main categories (logical vs. physical), which can be the same in simple systems, or may be different. The system converting from logical to physical addresses is the MMU (Memory Management Unit) and the conversion scheme vary with the architecture of the system.

One particular (family of) conversion schemes are those employing *virtual memory*, and thus the logical address in such a system is also called *virtual address*. Said in another way, a virtual address is a logical address on a system with virtual memory. Virtual memory is called this way because a logical (i.e. virtual) address does not necessarily map to an actual physical memory address. The memory content addressed by a VA could well reside on disk and thus will need to be brought into main memory before it can be used, whereas on a system with no virtual memory a logical address always maps to a physical address, i.e. to some "real" memory (e.g. RAM, ROM or some register in a device if memory-mapped I/O is implemented).

Another, higher level, perspective is to consider an access to a VA only a *tentative access*. If the memory content being accessed is already in physical memory, access is granted. Otherwise an interrupt is generated (memory page miss) and an interrupt routine is called that will load the needed memory page into physical memory from its actual location (typically the page file on disk). That routine is also responsible for freeing some physical memory if there is no room left to load the requested page.